# bash time with nohup

Tags: bash, time

I want to know how much time it takes to run something in nohup.
I know this works:

```
$ time sleep 2

real    0m2.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

But why it doesn't work with nohup?

```
$ nohup time sleep 2 &
[1] 29456
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'time': No such file or directory

[1]+  Exit 127                nohup time sleep 2
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It doesn't work because `time` is a shell keyword. There are external `time` binaries, but you don't appear to have one installed. This will likely work:

```
nohup bash -c 'time sleep 2'
```

Comment: Right. And we'll see in "nohup.out" that it takes just over 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I installed time rpm instead, but it works now too.