# Using nohup and time with different outputs

Tags: bash, io-redirection, executable, time, nohup

I want to run an executable `main` and redirect all outputs to `/dev/null`, meanwhile I measure its runtime with `time` and write the results to `runtime.out`. Since the task is long I also have to run the whole thing with `nohup`.

 I tried the following:

 `nohup time ./main &> /dev/null &> runtime.out &` 

 This just outputs everything to `runtime.out`.
I don't need the output of `main` just the runtime, saved into a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/time/time.1.en.html) has something made to be used for this:

```
nohup time -o runtime.out ./main &> /dev/null &
```

If it was scripted and didn't require a tty, I'd rather use `setsid` than `nohup + &`, because it "daemonizes" better, and can still be sent a `HUP` signal if needed.

```
setsid time -o runtime.out ./main </dev/null &>/dev/null
```

Also note that here (as in OP's question) `time` is `/usr/bin/time`, which has a different output format than bash's builtin `time` command. It appears that `/usr/bin/time --portability` gives a similar output if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Through some trial & error and stealing inspiration from [bash time with nohup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/bash-time-with-nohup?rq=1) , I came up with the following:

```
$ nohup bash -c 'time ./main &> /dev/null' > runtime.out &
[1] 23178
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
$ 
[1]+  Done                    nohup bash -c 'time ./main &> /dev/null' > runtime.out
$ cat runtime.out 

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.002s
```

This will redirect `stdout` of `time` to `runtime.out`, print `stdout` of `nohup` to the terminal, and redirect `stdout` and `stderr` of `main` to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do the right thing:

```
$ time > runtime.out nohup ./main &> /dev/null &
```

Comment: When I try this, I see the `stdout` of `time` on the terminal and `runtime.out` is empty. (Where `main` is a simple shell script with an `echo`)

Comment: Interesting, because when I ran that, I saw no output, and had a `runtime.out` file with the output of `time` therein.  Redirecting `main`'s output to `main.out` resulted in the expected two files rightly populated.

Comment: Strange. Could it be shell differences? I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release`

Comment: `4.4.19(1)-release` over here.  :shrug:

Comment: sadly this does not do the job.